# How to add args in knobs that can eidt/add html and add Event

Tags: javascript, storybook

```
import { storiesOf, html } from "@open-wc/storybook";
import { withKnobs, text, boolean, number, select, object, array } from "@storybook/addon-knobs";
import { withNotes } from "@storybook/addon-notes";

import marked from "marked";
import notes from "./notes.md";

storiesOf("Explore", module)
    .addDecorator(withNotes)
    .addDecorator(withKnobs)
    
  .add("Brands", () => {
    return html`
      <style>
          .container{
             
            }
      </style>
      <div class="container">
         <button>Help</button>
      </div>
    `;
  },  {
    notes: marked(notes)
  },
  {
        knobs: {
            escapeHTML: false
        }
    });
```

As there is less to no documentation for storybook v4 documentation for web component, I want to find a way to make my button text editable and made a way that I can move add flexbox on button so I can align button to right, left or center.

I have tried adding Event Listener but not sure if that is right way to do in Storybook 4.1